# how to combine codeigniter and angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've see a lot posts about codeigniter and angularjs work together,but most of them are about retriving data and pass data .My question is more basic.

I run the site through php,then every thing is ok,means that angularjs work properly.But when I run it through controller,it didn't work.what's wrong?Here are parts of my codes:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
```

---

```
class First extends CI_Controller{

  public function index(){
      $this->load->view('first');
  }

}
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

---

my controller file is first.php,view file is first.php as well.when I browse the site by http://localhost/ci_ngtest/index.php/first, the first and last name input are blank,and the Full name show {{firstName + " " + lastName}} instead of John Doe

---

here is my project structure:

```
 --application
 --node_modules
   --angular
     --angular.js
   --angular-material
 --system
 --user_guide
 --somefiles(somefiles below)
```

Comment: Where you added `angularjs` library in your view ...?

Comment: in the body,<script src="../../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>

Comment: i also add <script src="../../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>

Comment: check in console what errors you are getting ..?

Comment: Failed to load:http://localhost/node_modules/angular/angular.js  resource the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I did not set the base_url

Comment: where is your angular.js file in codeigniter structure..?

Comment: i've edit @Yash the post

Comment: check with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure script path properly:

1. First set `base_url` inside  application\config\config.php:

`$config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/ci_ngtest/index.php/';`

2. load library inside application\config\autoload.php

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

3. configure script path:

`<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>`